# Matlab private/nested function in OOP

Tags: matlab, oop

I have a function that has several sub-functions, everything is a part of a handle class. This could be illustrated by the following (there is no circular dependence of the private functions, some stuff is dependent on the object):

```
function out = f1(obj, in)
   out = f2(obj, f3(in * obj.Thickness));
end

function out = f2(obj, in)
   out = f3(in / obj.NumLayers);
end

function out = f3(in)
   out = in;
end
```

With the file `f1.m` inside `@MyClass` folder.

I decided to put all those files in the class and remove that `@MyClass` folder during making of the final package (I am at that point now).

At this point, class structure is

```
classdef MyClass < handle
properties
   prop1
end
methods
   function obj = MyClass(varargin) ...
   function out = f1(obj, in)
end
methods (Access = private)
   function out = f2(obj, in)
end
methods (Access = private, Static)
   functions out = f3(obj, in)
end
end
```

Everything is in `MyClass.m`, f2 and f3 are private, but obviously seen to other functions inside the class. I find this slightly problematic as some functions have slightly similar names (because they do similar, although not the same things) and could mislead whoever maintains the code - including me later on.

Nested functions are another option I briefly considered, but there I really dislike the "shared parameters" bit (which is the point of those nested functions) for my use case, because to me it sounds this is prone to introduce errors.

Am I missing any better solution here, or should I stick to the current private functions thing?

Comment: I feel like it would be much clearer to just *show* your file structure than describing it. If you have functions private to a given class then they shouldn't be polluting the namespace...

Answer (score 1):

One solution is as follows:

```
classdef name

   properties
      ...
   end

   methods

      function out = f1(obj, in)
         out = f2(obj, f3(in * obj.Thickness));
      end

   end
end

function out = f2(obj, in)
   out = f3(in / obj.NumLayers);
end

function out = f3(in)
   out = in;
end
```

This makes them class-private, but not member methods. I'm not sure that these private functions can access private members of the class.

The alternative is to create [private member functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/method-attributes.html):

```
classdef name

   properties
      ...
   end

   methods

      function out = f1(obj, in)
         out = f2(obj, f3(in * obj.Thickness));
      end

   end

   methods (Access=private, Hidden=true)

      function out = f2(obj, in)
         out = f3(in / obj.NumLayers);
      end

      function out = f3(in)
         out = in;
      end

   end
end
```